# How to get value of Radio button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button

I want my code to get values 1,2 and 3 from the following radio buttons rather than their names. The value I want is in data type int but I am having trouble in creating empty int variable for if else statement.

o Male

o Female

o Other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simular construction

```
int value = 0;
if(radioButton1.Checked)
  value=1;
else if(radioButton2.Checked)
  value=2;
else if(radioButton3.Checked)
  value=3;
else
  value=0;
```

Comment: I'm getting error cannot implicitly convert type string to int with this code.

Comment: r.CustomerPhone = txtNumber.Text;
            int value = "";
            r.CustomerGender = value;
            if (rbmale.Checked)
                value = 1;
            else if (rbFemale.Checked)
                value = 2;
            else if (rbOthers.Checked)
                value = 3;

Comment: change ```int value="";``` to ```int value=0```;

Comment: @AbinabDangi is it help you ?

Comment: The last `else` is not necessary. You can omit it.